# Boolean array reordering in O(1) space and O(n) time

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

The problem is taken from [Elements of Programming Interviews](http://elementsofprogramminginterviews.com/):

Given an array A of n objects with Boolean-valued keys, reorder the array so that objects that have the key false appear first. **The relative ordering of objects with key true should not change.** Use O(1) additional space and O(n) time.

I did the following, it preserves the relative ordering of objects with key true and uses O(1) additional space, but I believe its time complexity is O(n*n!).

```
public static void rearrangeVariant4(Boolean[] a) {
  int lastFalseIdx = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].equals(false)) {
      int falseIdx = i;
      while (falseIdx > lastFalseIdx) {
        swap(a, falseIdx, falseIdx-1);
        falseIdx--;
      }
      lastFalseIdx++;
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone has an idea on how to solve it in O(n) time?

Comment: Closely related, [Dutch National Flag Problem](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeAlgDS/Sort/Flag/).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
boolean array[n]; // The array
int lastTrue = n;
for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; --i) {
  if (array[i]) {
    swap(array[--lastTrue], array[i]);
  }
}
```

After every iteration all elements after `lastTrue` are true. No two true elements are swapped because if there was a true element between `i` and `lastTrue` it would have been encountered already and moved behind `lastTrue`. This runs in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` memory.

Comment: very nice! clean and efficient!

Comment: Consider this: T0 F0 F1 T1. T1 is true, swap with itself, mark as last true. F1 false, skip. F0 false, skip. T0 true, swap with position left of T1. We have F1 F0 T0 T1. The order of the F's is wrong.

Comment: The OP only required the relative ordering among true values to be preserved.

Comment: Ah, right. I was trying to do something harder ... Should pay closer attention. Thanks.

Comment: This uses more than O(1) memory, since it takes at least log2(n-1) bits to store `lastTrue`.

Comment: @Ricky [Don't fall into this trap](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-17.html). In any case we are talking about Java so ints (and array sizes) are limited to 32bit, so assuming constant time for operations on and memory for single numbers is both more useful and simpler.

Comment: @Ricky Yes it all depends on what computation model you want to use. It turns out that for a large variety of algorithms assuming that single integers take O(1) space and O(1) time for simple arithmetic operations is the most useful. Hence for many problems assuming that `reduce(arr, (t, e) -> t + e)` being O(n) is perfectly fine, although yes you could also go with O(nm) with m being the bit size - and for some problems this will indeed make a big difference.

Comment: I would consider it an improvement if the decrement did not occur inline. =/ Less to think about, less confusion.

Comment: @RickyDemer I've been struggling with the same observation, but this was helpful: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/how-can-we-assume-that-basic-operations-on-numbers-take-constant-time , especially the first answer.

Comment: I might note that also the loop index requires logn bits to store. This could be fixed by just decrementing n instead of i.

Answer (score 7):

## `Java` Code - if you are using a `Boolean[]` - objects:

**Time - O(1), Space - O(1)**

```
public static <T> void swap(T[] a, int i, int j) {
    T t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;
}
```

**Time - O(N), Space - O(1)**

```
public static Boolean[] getReorderBoolObjects(Boolean[] array) {
    int lastFalse = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (!array[i]) {
            swap(array, lastFalse++, i);
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

#### `Spock` Test Case:

```
def "reorder bools - objects"() {
    given:
    Boolean[] b = [false, true, true, true, false, true]

    when:
    getReorderBoolObjects(b)

    then:
    b == [false, false, true, true, true, true]
}
```

## `Java` Code - if you are using a `boolean[]` - primitives:

**Time - O(N), Space - O(1)**

```
public static boolean[] getReorderBoolPrimitives(boolean[] array) {
    int falseCount = 0;
    for (final boolean bool : array) {
        if (!bool) {
            falseCount++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = i >= falseCount;
    }
    return array;
}
```

#### `Spock` Test Case:

```
def "reorder bools - primitives"() {
    given:
    boolean[] b = [false, true, true, true, false, true]

    when:
    getReorderBoolPrimitives(b)

    then:
    b == [false, false, true, true, true, true]
}
```

Comment: The array contains objects with a boolean field. The whole object needs to be swapped into new position, not just the truth value.

Comment: "given an array A of n objects with Boolean-valued keys"

Comment: @EdwardDoolittle You are right, I read the question title as `boolean[]`.

Comment: It does not preserve the order. I know that boolean is simply too primitive to see consequences of not preserving the order of true elements.

Answer (score 3):

Let the array have 0 based index and let it have `n` elements. Then you can do the following  ( pseudo code below )

```
     // A[] is your array
     i = 0
     k = 0
     for i from 0 to n-1
          if A[i] is true
             swap A[i] and A[k]
             increment k
```

Time complexity is `O(n)` and extra space is only used for two variables `i` and `j` so memory is `O(1)`. This way **ordering is preserved** amongst false and true values. ( This method puts true ones first you can change it according to your requirement ).

Comment: Yes the ordering is preserved, but the array starts with true values instead of false. (Maybe reversing it in O(n) time would do the trick ?)

Comment: Just do it back to front instead of front to back.

Comment: or just test for false values instead of true. change `if A[i] is true` to `if A[i] is false`

Comment: @ubica: Nope. That will preserve the order of the false-keyed elements while putting them at the beginning. What you want is to preserve the order of the true-keyed elements while putting them at the end.

Comment: Replace `true` with `false`. Doesn't this then reorder some of the true values? You need to insert rather than swap, no?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that  2k for fixed k is O(1), and 2n is O(n).  Construct a second array, and copy elements from the source array to the target array, adding elements with key `false` at one end and key `true` at the other. you can scan the array once to find out where the boundary must be.

Comment: The OP wanted O(1) additional space. How can you create an additional array in O(1) space. What is k referring to?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void rearrange(boolean[] arr) {
          int invariant = arr.length-1;
          for (int i = arr.length -1; i >= 0; i --) {
            if ( !arr[i] ) {
              swap( arr,i,invariant);
              invariant--;
            }
          }
    }
    private static void swap(boolean arr[] , int from ,int to){
        boolean temp = arr[from];
        arr[from]=arr[to];
        arr[to]=temp;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.