# Partially sorting a list based on a boolean value

Tags: java, java-8

Say I have a list of objects and I want to partition them within the same list based on whether or not a certain attribute of the object contains a specific string.

```
SomeClassA someClass: 
   String attributeA;
   ... (other attributes)
```

For example, say I have:

```
List<SomeClassA> someListA = (a list of SomeClassA);
```

And I want to put all instances of `SomeClassA` where `attributeA` contains "_DUD" after all instances where `attributeA` does NOT contain the String.

One option:
I know we can loop through the List, create and add to two lists based on whether or not the condition is true (contains "_DUD") and then add the second list after the first list, but is there a way to do it without creating these intermediate Lists?

I would prefer not doing a full sort since the order doesn't really matter. We just want all the instances containing _DUD attributes together.

(This is a simplified example with names replaced, of course, but I hope it got the overall need across)

Thanks!

Comment: `somListA.sort(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.attributeA.endsWith("_DUD")).reversed());`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723998/boolean-array-reordering-in-o1-space-and-on-time

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following algorithm:

- Going from the start of the list find next element containing "_DUD"
- Going from the end of the list find next element not containing "_DUD"
- Swap the elements
- Repeat until you meet

Answer (score 0):

You could use the comparator that is suggested in comments; I've also played with some little other approach:

```
newList = "A_DUD", "B_DUD", "nope", "nope2", "C_DUD", "D_DUD", "nope3"


for (int i = list.size() - 1; i > 0; --i) {

        if (!newList.get(i).contains("_DUD") && !newList.get(i - 1).contains("_DUD")) {
            int j = i - 1;
            do {
                --j;
            } while (j >= 0 && !newList.get(j).contains("_DUD"));

            if (j < 0) {
                break;
            }

            Collections.swap(newList, j, j + 1);
            ++i;
        }

        else if (!newList.get(i).contains("_DUD") && newList.get(i - 1).contains("_DUD")) {
            Collections.swap(newList, i, i - 1);
        }
    }
```